# Jquery filter checkbox array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to make filter with checkbox array using jquery. It works fine when only one checkbox is selected but when I select two or more checkboxes it doesnot show all the divs. Could you please help me to find my mistake.

http://jsfiddle.net/EducateYourself/vr8noyyL/19/

```
<div id="filters">
    <div class="filterblock">
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="cola" class="category">
        <label for="check1">Cola</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filterblock">
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="fanta" class="category">
        <label for="check2">Fanta</label>
    </div>
    <div class="filterblock">
        <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="sprite" class="category">
        <label for="check3">Sprite</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to filter using *and* (divs that have all the selected tags) or using *or* (divs that have one of the selected tags)?

Comment: I want to filter using OR (divs that have at least one of the selected tags)

Comment: I have just updated jsfiddle link

Comment: It's great to post a JS fiddle link, but you should also include the code you are having problems with in the question itself. That way, the question can be read and understood even if the fiddle would not be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery `filter()` method and, use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.category').on('change', function () {
        //select all target elements, hide them, and filter ....
        $('.resultblock').hide().filter(function() {
            //initialize flag
            var found = -1;
            //save reference to current element for use in .each
            var that = $(this);
            //check if current element has any of the checked tags
            $(':checkbox[name=check]:checked').each(function() {
                if( that.data('tag').split(' ').indexOf( this.value ) > -1 ) {
                    //set flag
                    found = 1;
                    //exit .each, no more iterations needed
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //only elements where found is set to 1 would be returned
            return found > -1;
        //show elements in result set
        }).show();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/vr8noyyL/15/)

And, if you want the pages to start off *correctly* - nothing showing as no tag checkbox is selected - just trigger the `change` event when the page loads.

```
        ....
        //show elements in result set
        }).show();
    }).change(); //<<<<----
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/vr8noyyL/17/)

**UPDATE**

In order for *selecting all* and *selecting none* to both show everything, update DEMO 1 as follows:

```
            ....
            }).length > 0 || (found = 1); //<<<<<---
            return found > -1;
        }).show();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/vr8noyyL/18/)

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Demo 1 is ok for me. The only problem is when I uncheck all the checkboxes, it displays nothing but I want it to show all the divs.

Comment: Please take a look at DEMO 3.

Comment: it seems my code works as well after some editing (pls check the new jsfiddle) . I just hide all the divs before filtering them

Comment: Sounds good. Now you have options. If you like, you can delete the question or update it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle doesn't work because you don't have jQuery included. in the left dropdown box. But once you include jQuery it works somewhat. The question is how do you want to filter.

If 2 items are checked do you want to show those that have either item (inclusive)? Or do you want to show those items that have both (exclusive)?

Start by getting all the filters in an array:

```
 $('.resultblock').hide();
 var values = $("#filters input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
                          return $(this).val();
                        }).get();
```

Inclusive filter is easy:

```
 $.each(values, function(idx, val){
     $('.resultblock[data-tag*="' + val + '"]').show();
 });
```

Exclusive filter is a little harder:

```
$.each($('.resultblock'), function(i, block){
    var $self = $(block);
    var show = true;
    var tag = $self.data('tag');
    $.each(values, function(idx, val){
        if(tag.indexOf(val) === -1){
            show = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    if(show){
        $self.show();
    }
});
```

here's a fiddle showing both: the inclusive is currently commented out: http://jsfiddle.net/vr8noyyL/16/